# Single Table for Class with Abstract Property

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I'm trying to create an entity class where one of the properties is an abstract class, and I want it stored with the properties as a single row in a single table.

I get one of the issues is mapping it back to the correct implementation of the abstract property class, but I know this can at least be solved when the abstract class is the entity. I just can't seem to get it to work properly when that abstract class is a property of the entity.

SQL:

```
create table my_entity(
  id bigint not null,
  version int not null,
  property_type varchar(255) not null,
  property1 varchar(255),
  property2 varchar(255),

  primary key(id)
);
```

MyEntity.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public final class MyEntity extends ConcurrencySafeEntity {

  @Id
  private final Long id;

  @Embedded
  private final MyProperty property;

  public MyEntity(Long id, MyProperty property) {
    this.id = Objects.requireNonNull(id);
    this.property = Objects.requireNonNull(property);
  }

  private MyEntity() {
    this.id = null;
    this.property = null;
  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public MyProperty getProperty() {
    return property;
  }
}
```

MyProperty.java:

```
@Embeddable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "property_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class MyProperty {

  private final String propertyType;

  public MyProperty(String propertyType) {
    this.propertyType = Objects.requireNonNull(propertyType);
  }

  protected MyProperty() {
    this.propertyType = null;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return propertyType;
  }
}
```

MyProperty1.java:

```
@DiscriminatorValue("PROPERTY_1")
public final class MyProperty1 extends MyProperty {

  private final String property1;

  public MyProperty1(String property1) {
    super("PROPERTY_1");
    this.property1 = Objects.requireNonNull(property1);
  }

  private MyProperty1() {
    this.property1 = null;
  }

  public String getProperty1() {
    return property1;
  }
}
```

MyProperty2.java:

```
@DiscriminatorValue("PROPERTY_2")
public final class MyProperty2 extends MyProperty {

  private final String property2;

  public MyProperty2(String property2) {
    super("PROPERTY_2");
    this.property2 = Objects.requireNonNull(property2);
  }

  private MyProperty2() {
    this.property2 = null;
  }

  public String getProperty2() {
    return property2;
  }
}
```

MyEntityRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

}
```

Code to produce error:

```
@Autowired
private MyEntityRepository repo;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void will_produce_error() {
    final MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity(1337L, new MyProperty1("123"));
    repo.save(myEntity);
    final String myProperty = repo.findById(1337L)
        .map(MyEntity::getProperty)
        .filter(MyProperty1.class::isInstance)
        .map(MyProperty1.class::cast)
        .map(MyProperty1::getProperty1)
        .orElseThrow();
    // myProperty should be "123"
}
```

Produces the following error:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : MyProperty; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : MyProperty

The error happens on this line:

```
repo.save(myEntity);
```

I'm probably missing some annotation or using one incorrectly or something. Anyone know how to get this to work properly? I don't want to have to change the structure of the class, only apply the correct annotations etc to make it work properly.

Comment: I am not sure if @Embedable is supported for `abstract` entity in this case. Because that would be composition and not inheritance.

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure though. I thought it might get applied to both of the extending classes. I can check if it makes a difference, though, normally you don't really need `@Embeddable` at all (I guess it might depend on the configuration or something).

EDIT: I got the exact same error when I applied that annotation to both the extending classes instead of the abstract one.

Comment: Try using `@Entity` instead. I did some digging and find this article https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: I think if I use `@Entity` it will be treated as a new "entity" AKA it's own separate table and it requires it's own id and everything. I want it to match into the table created from the SQL query I wrote.

EDIT: I tested it, and it complained about the entity not having a unique key. The unique key should be the primary key of the `my_entity` table.